# Что такое + в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу первую простую программу на Python и мне сложно понять, что такое в нем '+', почему он так по-разному используется. Он может складывать переменные с типом `int` (целые числа). Но, как я понимаю он и с другими категориями используется. И `str`, и `bool`, и т.д. Он же там по-разному действует? Как так получается?

Comment: + это оператор. А что вы имеете в виду под фразой «куда входит», непонятно

Comment: А «Int, Str, Bool» это не «категории», а встроенные типы данных (и пишутся они с маленькой буквы)

Comment: + в питоне входит туда же, куда входит +  в математике.

Answer (score 8):

Дополню ответы здесь.

Первое, введем терминологию на примере `a + b`

1. `a` - левый операнд
2. `+` - оператор сложения
3. `b` - правый операнд

От простого к сложному. Действие оператора сложения зависит от типов данных, с которым их используют.

#### Для числовых типов данных (`int`, `float`, `complex`)

Оператор сложения работает, как обычное математическое сложение

```py
# int + int = int
a = 1 + 2
print(type(a), a)
# out 
# <class 'int'> 3

# int + float или float + int = float
b = 1 + 2.1
c = 3.1 + 1
print(type(b), b, "\n", type(c), c)
# out
# <class 'float'> 3.1 
# <class 'float'> 4.1

# compex + int, int + complex, complex + complex, complex + float, float + complex = complex
d = (1 + 1j) + 1
e = 1 + (1 + 1j)
f = (1 + 1j) + (1 + 1j)
g = (1 + 1j) + 1.1
h = 1.1 + (1 + 1j)
print(f"{type(d), d}\n{type(e), e}\n{type(f), f}\n{type(g), g}\n{type(h), h}\n")
# out
# (<class 'complex'>, (2+1j))
# (<class 'complex'>, (2+1j))
# (<class 'complex'>, (2+2j))
# (<class 'complex'>, (2.1+1j))
# (<class 'complex'>, (2.1+1j))
```

Здесь стоит обратить внимание на комплексную запись числа `(1 + 1j)`. Оператор сложения определяет тип данных, как `complex`.

#### Для последовательностей (`str`, `list`, `tuple`, `dict`)

В данных типах данных появляется такой термин, как конкатенация. Что буквально переводится с латыни `присоединение цепями; сцепле́ние`

##### `str`

Конкатенировать можно только строку со строкой. В любом другом случае, вы будете получать ошибку

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Пример

```py
a = "abcdef"
b = "ghi"
c = a + b
print(type(c), c)
# out 
# <class 'str'> abcdefghi
```

##### `list`, `tuple`

Операция сложения для списков и кортежей тоже называется конкатенацией

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = a + b 
print(type(c), c) 
# out
# <class 'list'> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

e = (1, 2, 3, 4) 
f = (5, 6, 7, 8) 
g = e + f 
>>> print(type(g), g) 
<class 'tuple'> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

Если складывать с другими типами данных, результатом будет исключение `TypeError`

##### `dict`

Не поддерживается операция сложения.

#### Булевый тип (`bool`)

Здесь надо принять такую условность `True = 1`, `False = 0`. И оператор сложения с данным типом данных можно рассматривать, как сложение с числами `1 и 0`

```py
e = True + False   # bool + bool
f = True + 10      # bool + int
g = True + 11.1    # bool + float
print(type(e), e)
print(type(f), f)
print(type(g), g)

# out
# <class 'int'> 1
# <class 'int'> 11
# <class 'float'> 12.1
```

#### Чуть сложнее.

При использовании оператора сложения в python вызывается метод `__add__()`. Буквально, для выражения `a + b`, где `a` - это экземпляр класса, в котором определен метод `__add__()`, будет вызываться следующая конструкция `a.__add__(b)`.

У каждого типа данных можно спросить документацию по данному методу

```py
>>> int.__add__.__doc__
'Return self+value.'
>>> str.__add__.__doc__
'Return self+value.'
>>> dict.__add__.__doc__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'dict' has no attribute '__add__'
```

Небольшой пример переопределения `__add__()`

```py
>>> class MyType5:
...     def __init__(self) -> None:
...         self.value = 5
...     def __add__(self, value):
...         return self.value + value
...
>>> my = MyType5()
>>> my + 1
6
```

В примере наглядно показано, что переопределение метода `__add__()` влияет на оператор сложения. Важно отметить, что здесь важен порядок слева направо. То есть метод `__add__()` должен быть определен у левого операнда

Если поменяем порядок

```py
>>> 1 + my   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'MyType5'
```

То есть у типа данных `int` определен метод `__add__()`, но ему не известно, что делать с моим типом данных

Comment: Очень полезно, спасибо. Особо интересно относительно булевых операций. Но логично, что для логического сложения (каламбур тавтологический:-)) надо использовать `&`, а не `+`

Comment: @Сергей разные задачи. Когда надо посчитать количество `True` в каком нибудь итерируемом объекте, можно не вводить отдельно счетчик интовый, а просто складывать все сущности. На выходе будет количество `True`-сущностей. Так же можно использовать и `sum`-метод. пример `sum([True, False, True])`. Результат будет `2`.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше почитать учебник прежде, чем писать, иначе будут сюрпризы. `+` много куда входит, просто действует по-разному (и для `int`, и `str`, и `bool`) А учитывая динамическую типизацию, вопрос ещё веселее.
Вот несколько примеров:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 'Петя - '
d = 'Маша'
e = True
f = False

print ('a+b', a+b) # Печать: 11
print ('c+d', c+d) # Печать: Петя - Маша 
print ('e+f', e+f) # Печать: 1 (а вовсе не False:-)
print ('a+e', a+e) # Печать: 6 
print ('a+f', a+f) # Печать: 5
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Answer (score 4):

Вы путаете типы данных с операторами. "+" это арифметический оператор, а перечисленные вами  Int, Str, Bool, это типы данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
>>> 2+3
5
```

Советую вам почитать про операторы и типы данных, тогда вы научитесь отличать одно от другого.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: Используйте текстовые блоки для написани кода, я сейчас подправлю, а вы в будущем используйте